# Splitting a Python string every nth character iterating backwards

Tags: python, binary

I'm working on a program that converts numbers to binary and vice versa.  When the user enters a binary string such as `1011110110` it's converted to decimal and printed.  I also want to print out the users inputted string like `10 1111 0110`.

I have tried

```py
print("Binary \t=\t " + ' '.join(binaryString[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(binaryString), 4)))
```

Which will print out as `1011 1101 10`.  I'm wanting the spaces to start at the end of the string working forward like `10 1111 0110`.

Comment: You can left-pad your string with spaces so that your slicing works: `s = ' '*(len(s) % 4) + s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `[::-1]` in two places in your code:

```
' '.join(binaryString[::-1][i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(binaryString), 4))[::-1]
```

p.s `[::-1]` reverse the string, so you just reverse it, add spaces in your way and then reverse again to proper initial order.

Comment: I tried what you said and this was my outcome
Enter the binary number or -1 to stop:  111000000111

Binary  =  0111 0000 1110

Comment: >>> binaryString = "111000000111"
>>> ' '.join(binaryString[::-1][i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(binaryString), 4))[::-1]
'1110 0000 0111'
>>>

Comment: have you placed `[::-1]` in two places?

Comment: print("Binary \t=\t " + ' '.join(binaryString[::-1][i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(binaryString), 4)[::-1]))

Comment: you have misplaced the second `[::-1]`

Comment: `print("Binary \t=\t " + ' '.join(binaryString[::-1][i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(binaryString), 4))[::-1])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the module `%` operator to know how many "overflow" numbers you have, then partition the remainder every 4th:

```
def  neat_print(s):
    ls = len(s)
    start = ls % 4
    rv, s = s[:start], s[start:]
    return ' '.join([rv] + [s[i:i+4] for i in range(0,ls-start,4)]).strip()

for k in ["1010101010"[:end] for end in range(2,10)]:
    print(k, "->", neat_print(k))
```

Output:

```
10 -> 10
101 -> 101
1010 -> 1010
10101 -> 1 0101
101010 -> 10 1010
1010101 -> 101 0101
10101010 -> 1010 1010
101010101 -> 1 0101 0101
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive approach:

```
def rGroup(S,size=4,sep=" "):
    return S if len(S)<=size else rGroup(S[:-size],size,sep) + sep + S[-size:]
```

output:

```
rGroup('1010101010') # '10 1010 1010'

rGroup('12345678',3,',') # '12,345,678'

binaryString = "1011110110"    
print("Binary \t=\t " + rGroup(binaryString)) # Binary  =    10 1111 0110
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out where to start your cursor to print out the correct number at the start

```
string_length = len(binaryString)

# Start position is the remainder when dividing by 4
start_pos = string_length % 4

output_items = []

# Get first item
if start_pos > 0:
 output_items.append(binaryString[0:start_pos])

# Go through the remainder of the string
for i in range(start_pos, string_length, 4):
 output_items.append(binaryString[i:i+4])

print("Binary \t=\t " + ' '.join(output_items))
```